# WPF nullreference exception thrown on Button when value converter in prior Label is in place

Tags: wpf, data-binding, nullreferenceexception

**TLDR:**
A Nullreference exception is thrown when XAML parsing any button element when another unrelated element has databinding and value converter. When the buttons are commented out, or the databinding is removed the form works.

I have a WPF UserControl with a list box in it which has a DataTemplate with multiple controls in it. I also have a bool to visibility value converter which I use in different locations in the control. I added a new static reference of the converter to the control (different bool to visibility values) and bind it to a label and suddenly the app crashes upon loading the control.

I remove the binding and all is well again. The converter is not at fault though; I put break points in its constructor as well as the convert methods, and it never reaches it. The exception is in the parsing of the XAML, not at the label, but at the first button declared, which is 100% unrelated to the label. If I remove the value converter binding from the label, the XAML parses correctly and the button has no issues.

However, to complicate things, if I comment out that button and every other button in the XAML, it also parses correctly and the value converter works without a problem.

What am I missing?

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Customer_Management.OpportunityControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
                     xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Customer_Management"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" MaxHeight="200" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="ucOpp">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <l:NullToVisibilityConverter NullValue="Hidden" NonNullValue="Visible" x:Key="NullToHidden"></l:NullToVisibilityConverter>
    <l:BoolToVisibilityConverter TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Hidden" x:Key="TrueToVisible"></l:BoolToVisibilityConverter>
    <l:BoolToVisibilityConverter TrueValue="Hidden" FalseValue="Visible" x:Key="FalseToVisible"></l:BoolToVisibilityConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ScrollViewer>
<ListBox Name="lbxOpps" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>

                        <StackPanel>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Opportunity.Name}" Margin="0,1,3,1"></TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Opportunity.Amount, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" Margin="0,1,3,1"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="btnFinishOrder" Click="btnFinishOrder_Click">Finish Order</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock  Margin="0,1,3,1">Invoice #</TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Name="tbxInvoiceNumber" Text="{Binding Path=InvoiceNumber}"></TextBox>

                            </StackPanel>

                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Batches}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsOcc, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisible}}">OCC #:</Label>

                                                <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="cboLicense" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SLicense}"  DisplayMemberPath="LicenseID" 
                                                                SelectedValuePath="LicenseID"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ucOpp, Path=Licenses}">
                                                </ComboBox>
                                                <!--<Button Margin="0,0,3,0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cboLicense}"  Click="Button_ClearContorl">X</Button>-->
                                                <Label Margin="0,0,3,0" >R #:</Label>
                                                <!--<Button ToolTip="Click to change" Name="btnLicFile" Click="Button_Click"  >LIC File</Button>-->
                                                <!--<Button Margin="0,0,3,0"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=btnLicFile}" Click="Button_ClearContorl"  ToolTip="Clear">X</Button>-->
                                                <Label Margin="0,0,3,0" >P #:</Label>
                                                <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="cbxPNum" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=PNum}"   DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                                            SelectedValuePath="Id"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ucOpp, Path=Nums}">
                                                </ComboBox>
                                                <!--<Button Margin="0,0,3,0"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbxPNum}"  Click="Button_ClearContorl" ToolTip="Clear">X</Button>-->
                                                <Label Margin="0,0,3,0" >U #:</Label>
                                                <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="cbxUNum" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UNum}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                                            SelectedValuePath="Id"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ucOpp, Path=Nums}">
                                                </ComboBox>
                                                <!--<Button Margin="0,0,3,0"   DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbxUNum}" Click="Button_ClearContorl" ToolTip="Clear">X</Button>-->
                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LawnGreen" FontSize="24" Opacity="0.8" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsProcessing, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisible}}"></Label>
                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsProcessing, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisible}}">Processing...</Label>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


</ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

ValueConverter:

```
public sealed class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Visibility TrueValue { get; set; }
    public Visibility FalseValue { get; set; }

    public BoolToVisibilityConverter()
    {
        // set defaults
        TrueValue = Visibility.Visible;
        FalseValue = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
            return null;
        return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Equals(value, TrueValue))
            return true;
        if (Equals(value, FalseValue))
            return false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you already have a workaround. Anyway, convert method should never return NULL in this case. This should be OK: if (!(value is bool)) return FalseValue;